# Writing custom Route Prefix in ASP.NET WebApi

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am trying to write a custom route prefix in asp.net WebApi. Following is the class I have written (was following a book).

```
public class ApiVersion1RoutePrefixAttribute : RoutePrefixAttribute
 {
    private const string RouteBase = "api/{apiVersion:apiVersionConstraint(v1)}";
    private const string PrefixRouteBase = RouteBase + "/";

    public ApiVersion1RoutePrefixAttribute(string routePrefix)
        : base(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(routePrefix) ? RouteBase : PrefixRouteBase + routePrefix) { }

 }
```

When I have build the solution , I got the following Error:

> "Error 1   'WebApiBook.Web.Common.Routing.ApiVersion1RoutePrefixAttribute': cannot derive from sealed type 'System.Web.Http.RoutePrefixAttribute'"

Here is my packages.config file:
   [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core version 5.0.0` which uses `System.Web.Http version 5.0.0` And in this version `RoutePrefixAttribute` is marked as sealed so you can not extend it:

```
namespace System.Web.Http
{
  /// <summary>
  /// Annotates a controller with a route prefix that applies to all actions within the controller.
  /// </summary>
  [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class, AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = false)]
  public sealed class RoutePrefixAttribute : Attribute
  {
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the route prefix.
    /// </summary>
    public string Prefix { get; private set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="T:System.Web.Http.RoutePrefixAttribute"/> class.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="prefix">The route prefix for the controller.</param>
    public RoutePrefixAttribute(string prefix)
    {
      if (prefix == null)
        throw Error.ArgumentNull("prefix");
      this.Prefix = prefix;
    }
  }
}
```

Either derive from `System.Web.Mvc.RoutePrefixAttribute` or update your `Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core` to latest version. Here is the implementation for version 5.2.3. As you can see the class is not `selaed` there:

```
namespace System.Web.Http
{
  /// <summary>
  /// Annotates a controller with a route prefix that applies to all actions within the controller.
  /// </summary>
  [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class, AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = true)]
  public class RoutePrefixAttribute : Attribute, IRoutePrefix
  {
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the route prefix.
    /// </summary>
    public virtual string Prefix { get; private set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="T:System.Web.Http.RoutePrefixAttribute"/> class.
    /// </summary>
    protected RoutePrefixAttribute()
    {
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="T:System.Web.Http.RoutePrefixAttribute"/> class.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="prefix">The route prefix for the controller.</param>
    public RoutePrefixAttribute(string prefix)
    {
      if (prefix == null)
        throw Error.ArgumentNull("prefix");
      this.Prefix = prefix;
    }
  }
}
```